# Unable to find the newly created git remote branch from command prompt

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Configured git repository locally able to work without any issue. Then I created new branch from git web interface for new task. Now the problem is unable to checkout the newly created branch.

`git checkout new-branch-name` giving following message.

> error: pathspec 'dev-SE-1844' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Also tried with the command `git branch -r` but unable to find the created branch in the list.

Comment: Is your remote set correctly, did you try `git fetch` before checking out the remote branch?

Comment: great, now found the branch and able to checkout after using command `git fetch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to do a `git fetch` before, I hope this helps